# Adding view to bottom of Table Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-tablelayout

I am working on an android project and I have a table layout. I have the Table Layout with one row in the XML layout file for the table headings. The rest of the table is populated dynamically from the result of an API.

I'm adding the views to the table layout, but the rows I'm adding dynamically appear above the table headings.

Below is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tblAuthenticatedDevices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:shrinkColumns="false"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/cardToolbar">
            <TextView
                android:text="Device Name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Last Logged In"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="From"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is how I am populating the rest of the table

```
JSONArray dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Defines.JSONElements.DATA);
            for (int i = 0; i < dataObject.length(); i++)
            {
                TableRow row = (TableRow)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_row_layout, tblAuthenticatedDevices, false);
                JSONObject deviceData = dataObject.getJSONObject(i);

                TextView txtDeviceName = new TextView(AuthenticatedDevices.this);
                txtDeviceName.setText(deviceData.getString("DeviceName"));
                row.addView(txtDeviceName);

                TextView txtLastLoggedIn = new TextView(AuthenticatedDevices.this);
                txtLastLoggedIn.setText(deviceData.getString("LastLoggedIn"));
                row.addView(txtLastLoggedIn);

                TextView txtLocation = new TextView(AuthenticatedDevices.this);
                txtLocation.setText(String.format("%s - %s", deviceData.getString("Country"), deviceData.getString("City")));
                row.addView(txtLocation);
                tblAuthenticatedDevices.addView(row);
            }
```

Just to re-iterate, the row data that I am dynamically adding to the table appears above the row headings I've added to my XML layout. I expected the row headings to appear, then below that would appear the rows that I am adding to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised what I've done wrong when I took another look this morning.

I've ended the Table Layout (i.e. I have `<TableLayout... />`) then I've added my TableRow but its outside the TableLayout.

Instead I have put my headings inside the TableLayout tag as below and it works as expected.

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tblAuthenticatedDevices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:shrinkColumns="false"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/cardToolbar">
            <TextView
                android:text="Device Name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Last Logged In"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="From"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I've been researching regarding TableLayouts where there is always a header included to them, and basically, all of them just adds the TableRow header first via code, in order for it to be on top. So here's what I did as a reference for you.. First, I just did a separate layout for the header.

> tr_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/tv_device_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="device name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_last_login"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="last_login" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_location"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="location" />

</TableRow>
```

Then in the layout of the activity where the tableLayout is, I just kept it empty, like so...

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.aalawi.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tblAuthenticatedDevices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:shrinkColumns="false"
        android:stretchColumns="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then in the code, I just add first the header, then iterated on some sample data afterwards. Also, I presume you also have a different layout for your table_rows as mentioned in the code you provided (***named table_row_layout***), so I just did something similar.

> tl_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_device_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_last_login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_location"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

</TableRow>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TableLayout tl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();
    }


    private void initViews() {
        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblAuthenticatedDevices);

        List<String> deviceNames = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
        List<String> lastLogin = Arrays.asList("11", "22", "33");
        List<String> location = Arrays.asList("111", "222", "333");

        // Add Header First...
        TableRow header = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tr_header, null);
        tl.addView(header);

        // Fill additional rows...
        for (int i = 0; i < deviceNames.size(); i++) {
            TableRow row = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tl_row, tl, false);
            TextView txtDeviceName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_device_name);
            TextView txtLastLoggedIn = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_last_login);
            TextView txtLocation = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

            txtDeviceName.setText(deviceNames.get(i));
            txtLastLoggedIn.setText(lastLogin.get(i));
            txtLocation.setText(location.get(i));

            tl.addView(row);
        }
    }

}
```

That resulted to this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this before you create your data rows to create the header:

```
        TableRow rowHeader = new TableRow(context);
          rowHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c0c0c0"));
          rowHeader.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
               TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

          //Title header for each column here
          String[] headerText={"ID","NAME","TYPE"};

          for(String c:headerText) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                  TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setTextSize(18);
            tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tv.setText(c);
            rowHeader.addView(tv);
          }
          tableLayout.addView(rowHeader);
```